# Configuración de una maquina virtual con Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

tengo una maquina virtual alojada en DigitalOcean, a la cual le instale Postgresql.

Configure el mismo de la siguiente manera:

1. En el archivo `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf`
   cambie de `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` a `listen_addresses = '*'`
2. En el archivo `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf`
   cambie de esto

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

a esto

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Una vez realizados estos cambios desde el usuario root ejecute:
`systemctl stop postgresql` y `systemctl start postgresql`

Por ultimo entre al usuario postgres de unix ejecute psql y ejecute el comando:
`ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';`

Y no toque nada mas en cuanto configuración del Postgresql.

Pero al tratar de establecer conexion con la BD desde PGAdmin
me pasa lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Valide los datos varias veces y los infresados en el formulario son correctos.

He realizado con antelación otras instalaciones de Postgresql y con solo estos cambios ya estaba y no tenia problemas al conectarme desde mi maquina en otra parte del mundo.

Seguramente me esta faltando hacer algo y no me doy cuenta el que.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta poner `localhost` en `Host name/address`

Comment: El problema no esta en tratar de entar a postgres desdee el servidor, sino que desde fuera del servidor.

Comment: Mueve la línea `host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       md5` al final del archivo, agrega el rango de direcciones ipv6: `host    all      all      ::/0             md5` y reinicia el servidor. Asegúrate de que el puerto sea el 5432 en `/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf` (opción `port`) y que el puerto esté abierto.

Comment: Por cierto, en el formulario que muestras ¿estás colocando la IP del servidor, o estás dejando la cadena `IP del servidor`?

Comment: Donde dice IP del servidor está la IP puse ese texto en Paint para que no se viese la IP